# System.IO.FileNotFoundException In multi-project solution

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, multi-project

So I've been stuck on this error for a good week now, and it has been very frustrating

[image]

(Impossible to load the file or assembly 'Audio.Default.Switcher.Wrapper.dll' or one of its dependencies. The specified module wasn't found)

I'm working with Visual Studio 2017 and I've downloaded [the SoundSwitch project](https://github.com/Belphemur/SoundSwitch), and everything is working perfectly fine. I'm able to run "SoundSwitch" without any errors.

The way the solution works (as I'm able to understand) is that the "SoundSwitch" C# project is the "master" and it has references to "Audio.Default.Switcher.Wrapper" as well as "SoundSwitch.UI.UserControls"

"Audio.Default.Switcher.Wrapper" as a reference to "AudioDefaultSwitcher"

- Both "Audio.Default.Switcher.Wrapper" and "AudioDefaultSwitcher" seem to compile as .dll files
- "SoundSwitch.UI.UserControls" cannot be started and is used for display stuff I guess
- "SoundSwitch" is the only startable project (not counting mine of course)

[image]

The K005_test is MY project, I've added it and it has references (only) to "SoundSwitch" and I'm trying to use the functions from the SoundSwitch project inside K005_test. And so far my K005_test project consists only of

**Program.cs** (where I get the error by the way)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace K005_test
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1()); //Exception thrown here
        }
    }
}
```

**Form1.cs** (where I put my code for the test)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace K005_test
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("This is a test");
            var test = SoundSwitch.Model.AppModel.Instance.AvailablePlaybackDevices; //Error this line exists
        }
    }
}
```

And when I run my K005_test project, it compiles and runs just fine, except when I **click the button** Then I get the error I posted above. Also the message box doesn't open.

What I've tried so far :

- Flipping everything to "x86" or "Win32", it seems that it might be related a problem with 64bit something
- Using references to both "Audio.Default.Switcher.Wrapper.dll" and "SoundSwitch" in K005_test
- copy "Audio.Default.Switcher.Wrapper.dll" pretty much everywhere and praying the gods
- Trying to understand where it looks for "Audio.Default.Switcher.Wrapper.dll" but I wasn't able to find anything when looking in the exception details

Nothing has helped in any way.

For anybody wondering, I've uploaded my entire project folder here

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1OABjDiZyF0B-1-b15_9lzMrPZ4UpyKqU

Comment: Does the project use some native dependencies?

Comment: Please include relevant code as text, not as images.

Comment: @Vlad you mean "System.<stuff>" references ? in that case all C# projects use them yes

Comment: @HereticMonkey I did that at first, but there wasn't any color and with the image i was able to add the arrow. I'll try to improve on that !

Comment: @Klue: No, I mean the dependencies on native DLLs. Having dependencies on native DLLs could explain the behaviour you see, as 32-bit DLL can't be loaded into 32-bit process.

Comment: @Vlad i'm not sure i understand. What project are you talking about ? All C# projects have references to DLLs like System.Deployment.dll (first exemple i saw) if it's what you mean by "native"

Comment: @Klue: Native DLL is e. g. a DLL written in native languages like C++

Comment: @Vlad oh okay i get it now ! So yes "K005_test" has reference to "SoundSwitch" which has reference to "Audio.Default.Switcher.Wrapper" (a C++ dll) which then has refernece to "AudioDefaultSwitcher" (also a C++ dll)

Comment: @Klue: Ok that should clear everything. Is AudioDefaultSwitcher a a 64-bit DLL? (https://superuser.com/questions/358434/how-to-check-if-a-binary-is-32-or-64-bit-on-windows)

Comment: @Vlad I've set the platform to Win32. But i forgot to mention that i've done some tests to "fix" the dll with a windows command and i got a "not a valid dll" or something (and your tests doesn't seem to work either, i can't find "PE" with the right characters after it)

Comment: @Vlad update : i've used the basic notepad and i was able to do the test ! it's a x86 file